# Is it possible to customize the text right click menu in windows 10?

Tags: windows, text, menu, explorer, right-click

Is it possible to customize this menu in windows 10?

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFcio.jpg>
```

Comment: This menu is the standard **Edit control** context menu. It can be updated by program (C++ or other language) with [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) and **EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART** event